# Unity Firebase Realtime Database - Get index of child in database

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to retrieve the index of an entry in my database. I can do this by ordering
the data then grabbing all of the data in my database and counting the elements up to the entry that I want to find the index of. However, this is not a viable solution when the database goes online.

I have tried to use StartAt but it returns `Season1` and `null`

```
databaseReference.Child("Leaderboards").Child("Season1").StartAt("Player0").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    print(task.Result.Key);
    print(task.Result.GetRawJsonValue());
});
```

I have also tried to use EndAt but it returns all of the data in `Season1`

```
databaseReference.Child("Leaderboards").Child("Season1").EndAt("Player0").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    print(task.Result.Key);
    print(task.Result.GetRawJsonValue());
});
```

I have also added `.OrderByValue()` after `.Child("Season1")` which works fine in `foreach(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot in task.Result.Children)` but without limiting the data received, there is no point.

Perhaps, I need to restructure my database (Which I am fully willing to do as it does not hold actual data yet) but I do not know what format would fit my needs.

The Database being worked on:

[image: Database Structure]

Answer (score 0):

#### Not getting any query reults

In your code you have an uppercase `P` in `Player0`, but in the database all keys use a lowercase `p` like `player0`. That might explain why your reads are not giving results, as queries in Firebase are case-sensitive.

#### Getting the index of a node

> I can [get the index] by ordering the data then grabbing all of the data in my database and counting the elements up to the entry that I want to find the index of. However, this is not a viable solution when the database goes online.

Unfortunately, counting the nodes before it is the only way to get the index of a node in the Firebase Realtime Database. There is nothing built into the database to get the index of a node, so even if it exposed an API for it - it would essentially be doing the same internally.

Comment: Yes, but I want to grab as little data as possible, IE sort the data then grab up to player (which I tried to do with EndAt). Also, the Player0 was a typo and not in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found out through extensive testing, the functions `StartAt()` and `EndAt()` for Firebase Realtime Database only search by value and not key.
In my case, all of my values are integers so my `StartAt()` and `EndAt()` functions must include an integer value to filter data. *Perhaps you can send a JSON string to filter objects but that requires further testing as the documentation is nonexistent*

The best solution to find an index while retrieving as little data as possible would be to loop through the database searching for the key.

A few relevant things that I discovered during my testing are:

- `.OrderByValue()` returns items in a low to high (0-100 and maybe a-z) format and cannot be changed
- `.StartAt(int value)` will begin by showing all values starting at the given value passed into the function **Inclusive**
- `.EndAt(int value)` will stop showing values from the given value passed into the function *oddly enough, this is also* **Inclusive**
- `.LimitToLast(int count)` will only retrieve the last `count` number of elements from the previous query which in my case, is safer to use than combining `.StartAt()` with `.EndAt()` as they can return an unknown amount of data
- `.LimitToLast(100).LimitToLast(5)` and `.LimitToLast(100).LimitToFirst(5)` both return the same 5 *last* values
- There may be some cases when using `.EndAt(int value).LimitToLast(int count)` does not return all of the elements at `value` which can prevent a recursive function from progressing. As stacking `.LimitToLast().LimitToFirst/Last()` only returns the last values you cannot use it to iterate through the elements in the database. In this case, you can use `.StartAt(int value).EndAt(int value)` to obtain all elements with that value which would unfortunately return up to the entire database. This issue would happen at the start of a season when all scores are 0. A possible workaround for this issue would be to check if the current element is 0 (lowest possible value) and then return the count of higher elements

*My example will be ran inside of an `IEnumerator` instead of `.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => { });` since I am updating on screen elements*

**Rough example:**

```
bool hasData = false;
int index = 0;

//start getting baseData
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSnapshot> getLeaderboardTask = databaseReference.Child(DB_LEADERBOARD).Child(season).OrderByValue().LimitToLast(100).GetValueAsync();

//wait for data to be loaded
while (!getLeaderboardTask.IsCompleted) yield return null;

//Check for player value
foreach (DataSnapshot snap in getLeaderboardTask.Result.Children)
{
    if (snap.Key.Equals(playerName))
    {
        hasData = true;

        //Do something with the data - Remember to get index, you should use `((int)getLeaderboardTask.Result.ChildrenCount) - index` because Firebase counts in ascending order

        break;
    }

    index++;
}

//check if we need to iterate deeper
if (!hasData)
{
    //get new task
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSnapshot> getLeaderboardTask = databaseReference.Child(DB_LEADERBOARD).Child(season).OrderByValue().EndAt(endAtValue).LimitToLast(100).GetValueAsync();

    //continue searching while data hasn't been found
    while (!hasData)
    {
        //Wait for current data
        while (!getLeaderboardTask.IsCompleted) yield return null;

        #region Check if we have the player ranks yet
        //get global Data
        if (!hasData)
        {
            int lastRank = 0;

            //loop through the data that we just grabbed to look for the player global rank
            foreach (DataSnapshot snap in getLeaderboardTask.Result.Children)
            {
                if (snap.Key.Equals(playerName))
                {
                    hasData = true;

                    //Do something with the data - Remember to get index, you should use `((int)getLeaderboardTask.Result.ChildrenCount) - index` because Firebase counts in ascending order

                    break;
                }

                lastRank = int.Parse(snap.GetRawJsonValue());
                index++;
            }

            //we did not find the player yet, look for them 1 step deeper
            if (!hasData)
            {
                //we are caught in a loop unable to look deeper, search through all elements at this value
                if (endAtValue == lastRank)
                {
                    getLeaderboardTask = databaseReference.Child(DB_LEADERBOARD).Child(season).OrderByValue().StartAt(endAtValue).EndAt(endAtValue).GetValueAsync();

                    //decriment globalEndAtValue in case we do not find it at the current value
                    endAtValue--;
                }
                else
                {
                    endAtValue = lastRank;

                    //we are not in a loop and can continue searching at lastRank
                    getLeaderboardTask = databaseReference.Child(DB_LEADERBOARD).Child(season).OrderByValue().EndAt(endAtValue).LimitToLast(100).GetValueAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```